# Unable to click on Stores > Configuration > General > INFORTIS THEMES - CONFIGURATION > Theme Settings

Tags: magento2, ultimo

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Infortis\Base\Model\System\Config\Source\Header\Position\Primarytopusermenuinsidemenu does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Infortis\Base\Model\System\Config\Source\Header\Position\Primarytopusermenuinsidemenu does not exist

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/SourceFactory.php:37]
#5 Magento\Config\Model\Config\SourceFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Field.php:443]
#6 Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field->_getOptionsFromSourceModel() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Field.php:379]
#7 Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field->getOptions() called at [generated/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Field/Interceptor.php:323]
#8 Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field\Interceptor->getOptions() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php:394]
#9 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->_initElement() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php:316]
#10 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->initFields() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php:256]
#11 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->_initGroup() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php:202]
#12 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->initForm() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form.php:542]
#13 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->_beforeToHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1098]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1103]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:673]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:564]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:540]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:520]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-config/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/edit.phtml:26]
#23 include() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php:129]
#27 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1099]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1103]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:673]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:564]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:540]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#66 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#67 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#68 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#69 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#70 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#71 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#72 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#73 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#74 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#75 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:961]
#76 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:492]
#77 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#78 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#79 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:193]
#80 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#81 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#82 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#83 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
```

Comment: run the di compile command ..

Comment: Please check my answer below, Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ran the below:

````
Compilation was started.
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 49 secs 373.0 MiB
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.```

cleaned cache...

Then ran:
```Then ran bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f```

Error still persists.
````

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the file **Primarytopusermenuinsidemenu.php** in the below path

> **/app/code/Infortis/Base/Model/System/Config/Source/Header/Position/**

If don't have the file then create the file and add the below code

```
<?php

namespace Infortis\Base\Model\System\Config\Source\Header\Position;

class Primarytopusermenuinsidemenu
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 'topLeft',              'label' => __('Top, Left')],
            ['value' => 'topCentral',           'label' => __('Top, Central')],
            ['value' => 'topRight',             'label' => __('Top, Right')],
            ['value' => 'primLeftCol',          'label' => __('Primary, Left Column')],
            ['value' => 'primCentralCol',       'label' => __('Primary, Central Column')],
            ['value' => 'primRightCol',         'label' => __('Primary, Right Column')],
            ['value' => 'mainMenu',             'label' => __('Inside Main Menu')],
            ['value' => 'userMenu',             'label' => __('Inside User Menu...')],
        ];
    }
}
```

Save the file and run the below command from Magento root directory.

> **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

File is there in above location as explained.

```
/{dir}/app/code/Infortis/Base/Model/System/Config/Source/Header/Position
```

issue still persists...